# Find entry's count of array elements in each array in documents

Tags: mongodb

I have collection with such documents:

```
[
    {p: [1, 2, 3, 4]},
    {p: [1, 2, 7, 9, 10]},
    {p: [3, 5]}
]
```

I want to know how many times each element of `p` in all documents appear in other document's `p`. The right result should be collection with such elements:

```
[
    {pElement: 1, count: 2},
    {pElement: 2, count: 2},
    {pElement: 3, count: 2},
    {pElement: 4, count: 1},
    {pElement: 7, count: 1},
    {pElement: 9, count: 1},
    {pElement: 10, count: 1},
    {pElement: 5, count: 1}
]
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an [*Aggregation Pipeline*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/#aggregation-pipeline) with the following stages:

1. Decompose the `p` arrays and generate one document for each element. You can use [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) operator in order to do that.
2. Group the generated documents based on the `p` value and count the occurrence of each one using the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) operator and [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum) accumulator operator.
3. Reshape the previous stage result to look like `{pElement: p, count: c}` using the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) operator.
4. And sort them based on the `count` value using [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) operator.

The final aggregation code would look like:

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([ 
            { $unwind: "$p" }, 
            { $group: { _id: "$p", count: { $sum: 1 } } }, 
            { $project: { _id: 0, pElement: "$_id", count: 1 } }, 
            { $sort: { count: -1 } }
])
```

The result would be:

```
{ "count" : 2, "pElement" : 3 }
{ "count" : 2, "pElement" : 2 }
{ "count" : 2, "pElement" : 1 }
{ "count" : 1, "pElement" : 5 }
{ "count" : 1, "pElement" : 10 }
{ "count" : 1, "pElement" : 9 }
{ "count" : 1, "pElement" : 7 }
{ "count" : 1, "pElement" : 4 }
```